# Best practice in jQuery to prevent multiple requests after reloading event listener for newly ajax created content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm building a small jQuery-based webshop-thingy.

On page load, I'm doing this sort of thing:

```
// Initialize fancybox, I use its Ajax content popup
init_fancybox();
// Fire up the event listeners for the dropdown add to cart boxes.
init_edit_shopping_cart();
```

Init fancybox does this:

```
function init_fancybox() {
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({ 
    'padding'    : '0px',
    'onComplete' : function(){ 
        $('.closefancybox').click(function(){parent.$.fancybox.close();})
        init_edit_shopping_cart();
    }
}); 
}
```

Init edit shopping cart puts items in the cart when a value is selected from a dropdown:

```
function init_edit_shopping_cart() {
    $('.amount_selector').change(function() {
        // Put the product with this id in the shopping cart with selected quantity
        edit_shopping_cart( $(this).attr('id').replace(/uid_/,"") , $(this).val() , 'update');
        $('#raster #' + $(this).attr('id')).val($(this).val());
    }); 
}
```

Then edit_shopping_cart() returns the newly created shopping cart, with newly added products. Products also have a product detail view (in Fancybox Ajax window). When it is called, I call the above functions again aswel. This causes the multiple loads.

So, the problem is that after firing up init_edit_shopping_cart(), my requests are loaded two, three (exponentially) times after everytime i call this function.

I've encountered this problem before, but I would like to know the best practice to handle such a situation. I've read about `.live()` but it seems to be depreceated in the newer jQuery versions.

Thanks for your speedy response.

Comment: I guess it really depends on what is in those functions. What you have essentially said here is "on page load I do stuff, what am I doing wrong?".  Live has only been deprecated in name, the concept is alive inside of .on()

Comment: Hi Sinetheta, I've added some more information. Could you give your view?

Comment: @GregPettit I will be happy to provide an answer now that there is enough information to do so. My COMMENT was that more clarification was required. The "answer" regarding .live() was at most a parenthetical aside.

Comment: @Sinetheta I meant to be encouraging, not scolding. ;-) I didn't notice the comment was to an incomplete question; my apologies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're perfectly right about .live() being a possible solution. Since your functions are making binds you will need to either target carefully to make sure that you are only putting handlers on newly added content, or get the work done with a one-time action like .live()

Without seeing what is in edit_shopping_cart() it's hard to guess what exactly is "firing twice", but there are a number of tricks you could use to avoid double initialisation:

**When you turn on a fancybox link, make sure it won't be targetted next time**

```
$("a.fancybox").removeClass('fancybox').fancybox(...
```

**Take your event listeners out of the "onComplete" callback, and run them once [globally](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (will affect all future .closefancybox)**

```
$('body').on('click', '.closefancybox', function(){
   parent.$.fancybox.close();
})
   .on('change', '.amount_selector', function() {
    edit_shopping_cart( $(this).attr('id').replace(/uid_/,"") , $(this).val() , 'update');
    $('#raster #' + $(this).attr('id')).val($(this).val());
});
```

**edited for additional information:** You'll want to move the "change" handler out to the document ready area as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Find the source at: http://labodega.chocolata.be/js/script.js

Fancybox isn't the problem, it's more edit_shopping_cart();
So I guess I should use `$('body').on('change','.amount_selector', function(){ init_edit_shopping_cart(); }` I will experiment with this later.

Comment: Works like a charm. Only problem is to load Fancybox in this way. I just reload it every time for now. It doesn't seem to fire doubles, so I guess my problem is solved. Thanks for your tips!